# Using MySQL functions with Node mysql2 library

Tags: node-modules, node-mysql, node-mysql2

This is my current request to insert data:

```
let record = {
    ip : '127.0.0.1',
    ...
};
conn.query('INSERT INTO events_log SET ?', [record]);
```

Is it possible to apply `INET6_ATON` function to the IP without converting it to a plain query? There are tens of parameters in this object and I wouldn't want to disassemble it.

The IP field is `varbinary(16)` type.

Comment: `INET6_ATON(?)` should work fine. You can put functions around placeholders, just don't quote the placeholder because that makes it a string.

Comment: @user3783243 Do you mean `let ip = 'INET6_ATON(127.0.0.1)';` ? ER_DATA_TOO_LONG, changing INET6_ATON to 123INET6_ATON doesn't trigger an error as well.

Comment: No, I meant in the query. `conn.query('INSERT INTO events_log SET INET6_ATON(?)` although maybe I'm mistaken about how node builds the identifiers to values... Is that SQL literal or pseudo? I think `INSERT INTO events_log (ip) values(INET6_ATON(?))` would work

Comment: Of course, it would work because its plain SQL, and I have the JS object which I have to pass to the node-mysql library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
let INET6_ATON = { toSqlString: function() { return 'INET6_ATON(' + mysql.escape(ip) + ')'; } };

let record = {
    ip : INET6_ATON,
    ...
};
conn.query('INSERT INTO events_log SET ?', [record]);
```